# Export Azure SQL Database using Powershell - Timeout

Tags: sql, powershell, azure, timeout, export

After searching everywhere for a solution with no luck, I'm hoping someone can help me here!

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script to export an Azure SQL database to a local server. When I run the script from PS ISE it runs fine.

When I run it manually using PowerShell or when I call the script via task scheduler, it starts the database export but stops at about 10% and goes to the next step of the script (delete old files, send notifications, etc).

The PS script uses `SqlPackage.exe` to export the file. The timeout on my connection string to Azure is **30** (default) but also tried **0** and huge values like **300000**...

I also played with `regedit` as suggested in another forum. The local instance on the server has unlimited timeout (although I don't think it really matters in this case).

It's worth mentioning that I'm running both PowerShell or scheduled task with elevated permissions. No errors are thrown.

Here's the part of the script that exports the database. Some of those variables aren't important for this bit though..

```
#General variables
$FileTimeStamp = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd-HHmm"

#Azure related variables
$ResourceGroupName = "blah" 
$ServerName = "blah" 
$SourceDatabase = "blah" 
$Instance = "$ServerName.database.windows.net"
$DBUserName = 'USER'
$DBPassword = 'PASSWORD'
$azureAccountName ="blah"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "BLAH" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)

#Local machine variables
$LocalInstance = "."
$LocalDestination = "D:\backups" 
$DacAssembly = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
$ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$ServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Database=$SourceDatabase;User ID=<USER>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" 
$OutputFile = "$LocalDestination\$SourceDatabase-$FileTimeStamp.bacpac" 


#Load DAC assembly.
Add-Type -Path $DacAssembly  
$Services = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $ConnectionString
if ($Services -eq $null) { exit }

#Start the actual export.
Start-Sleep -s 2
$Services.ExportBacpac($OutputFile, $SourceDatabase)
```

Any clues? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you pls post your script or if its big enough then please post the link of the script so that we can look into it. ? Are you running it with elevated mode? Are you getting any exception/error, if yes, please post the same.

Comment: Hi Ranadip, Code added to the main post. Cheers

Comment: Did an SSIS package the other day that connected to Azure. Had a timeout problem cause the server was blocking connections to Azure. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @ArturCorreia: The script seems fine. May be some permission issue. Are you running this in elevated mode. Moreover, I do not have the infra to test it right now. But probably I can check it tomorrow.
How the timeout works for you... Is there any restriction in your network for the same.

Comment: The strange thing is that it runs fine in PowerShell ISE though. The servers IP is also authorised to connect to Azure.

Comment: Yep, running in elevated mode. The export runs till about 10% so I suspect it can only be related to a timeout, but don't know where else to look for. No errors are thrown which is annoying too!